# How do I call a growable List in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am working on a flutter e-commerce application. My data are called dynamically. I created a Food_data class

```
class Food{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String imagePath;
  //final String description;
  final String category;
  final double price;
  final double discount;
  final double ratings;

  Food({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imagePath,
    //this.description,
    this.category,
    this.price,
    this.discount,
    this.ratings
  });


 final foods = [
    Food(
      id: "1",
      name: "Hot Cofee",
      imagePath: "assets/images/breakfast.jpeg",
      category: "1",
      price: 22.0,
      discount: 33.5,
      ratings: 99.0,
    ),
    Food(
      id: "1",
      name: "Grilled Chicken",
      imagePath: "assets/images/launch.jpeg",
      category: "2",
      price: 12.0,
      discount: 34.5,
      ratings: 69.0,
    ),
  ];

}
```

I need to access the food list in my homescreen.dart file below

```
//data
import 'data/food_data.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>{

//Assigning of foods into _foods
 List<Food> _foods = foods;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          children: <Widget>[
           HomeTopInfo(),
           FoodCategory(),
           SizedBox(height: 20.0),
           SearchField(),
           SizedBox(height: 20.0),
           Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Frequently Bought Foods",
              style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 18.0,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              ),
```

I have import the food_data.dart in my homescreen.dart class. I also called the **List _myFood = foods;**
The foods list will assing the details into _myFood.

Now in my flutter program it is seeing **foods** as not been initialize. But i have created it in my Food class.

Comment: You should create the variable from the outside of the class body. Otherwise, it'll be only available when an object of the class is instantiated.

Comment: Please expantiate.

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet you provided, you created the variable `foods` in the class body:

```dart
class Food {
    //...
    final foods = [
       Food(
         id: "1",
         name: "Hot Cofee",
         imagePath: "assets/images/breakfast.jpeg",
         category: "1",
         price: 22.0,
         discount: 33.5,
         ratings: 99.0,
       ),
       Food(
          id: "1",
          name: "Grilled Chicken",
          imagePath: "assets/images/launch.jpeg",
          category: "2",
          price: 12.0,
          discount: 34.5,
          ratings: 69.0,
       ),
    ];
}
```

So, in that way, to access the variable, you have to first create an instance of the class:

```dart
List<Food> _foods = Food(...).foods;
// List<Food> _foods = Food.foods; // Throw an error: Getter not found 'foods'
```

*Why?* Because, in that way, we're saying: *the final field `foods` must exist when this class has been instantiated*.

#### So, what can we do to make it accessible?

In fact, there are two alternatives:

You can declare the variable from the outside of the class body, so you can access it, independent of the existence of an instance:

```dart
class Food{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String imagePath;
  //final String description;
  final String category;
  final double price;
  final double discount;
  final double ratings;

  Food({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imagePath,
    //this.description,
    this.category,
    this.price,
    this.discount,
    this.ratings
  });
}

final foods = [
    Food(
      id: "1",
      name: "Hot Cofee",
      imagePath: "assets/images/breakfast.jpeg",
      category: "1",
      price: 22.0,
      discount: 33.5,
      ratings: 99.0,
    ),
    Food(
      id: "1",
      name: "Grilled Chicken",
      imagePath: "assets/images/launch.jpeg",
      category: "2",
      price: 12.0,
      discount: 34.5,
      ratings: 69.0,
    ),
];
```

```
List<Food> _foods = foods; // Works
```

Or, you can declare the field as `static`, which means the field will be considered a "class variable" and not an "object/instance variable" (which only exists when an instance of the class is created).

```dart
    //...
    static final foods = [
       ...
    ];
}
```

However, in my opinion, that is not the case to declare it as `static`, because `foods` is a "sample list of `Food`s", and not "a global unique field of the class `Food`".

#### Making the variable accessible to both the widget class and the widget state class

To make the variable accessible to both classes (the main class and the state class), the (perhaps) most appropriate way is declaring the local variable in the main class and accessing it in the state class via the `widget` variable:

```dart
import 'data/food_data.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   final List<Food> _foods = foods;

   @override
   _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>{
   List<Food> foods;

   // This is an option (you can do it in another way)
   @override
   void initState() {
      super.initState();
      foods = widget._foods;
   }

   //...
}
```

Or if you are declaring the variable as **a static field of the class**:

```dart
List<Food> _foods = Food.foods;
```

And, here is one example of use of this variable (from the inside of the `_HomeScreenState` class):

```dart
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widget._foods.length, //or 'foods.length'
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: Image.assets(widget._foods[index].imagePath),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey, // or other color you prefer
                onBackgroundImageError: (err) { print(err); }
            ),
            title: Text(widget._foods[index].name),
            subtitle: Text(widget._foods[index].price.toString()),
        );
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you chief. I went through your piece. So how do i make variable foods accessible in Homescreen.dart class?

Comment: Do you mean, the main class (`HomeScreen` class)? In the code snippet you posted, the variable is in the state class (`_HomeScreenState` class).

Comment: Yes. I need to make foods accessible in Homescreen class. Which after I will store it in List<FOOD> _foods = foods;

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: final foods, msu be accessible in Homescreen.dart class

Comment: The answer didn't help. I need to access the foods in the Food class inside the Homescreen.dart class.

Comment: Edited the answer again.

Comment: Thank you all. I later figure out the reason why I encountered the is. i declared foods inside the class. Which sin't suppose to be. I tried your answer its fine. Am ok now